# Generate folder and file within that folder using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to generate a folder and a file within that folder. Below is the function i wrote in Node.js. The problem is, I'm able to generate the folder but the file generation does not work.

Could anyone please help?

```
const createDir = (folderName) => {
  fs.mkdirSync(
    process.cwd() + '/' + folderName,
    { recursive: true },
    (error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error('An error occured', error);
      } else {
        console.log('Your directory is made!');
        fs.writeFile(`/${folderName}/${folderName}.js`, '', (error) => {
          if (error) {
            console.error('An error occured', error);
          } else {
            console.log('file created!');
          }
        });
      }
    }
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the path to the directory you created:

> ```
> process.cwd() + '/' + folderName,
> ```

This is the path to the directory you are putting the file in:

> ```
> `/${folderName}`
> ```

They need to be the same (and they won't be unless the current working directory is the filesystem root, which seems unlikely).

Comment: Don't you think they both are same as it gave me same result when I changed `process.cwd() + '/' + folderName` to ```process.cwd() + `/${folderName}` ```

Comment: I had to move my file creation step outside the else block to make it work.
`createDir(folderName); 
createFile(folderName);`